# Подключение CSS к Javascript (ASP MVC)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, javascript, css, visual-studio

Реализую подхват даты на страничке ASP MVC 2 при помощи datepicker из библиотеки jQueryUI. Для работы подключаю к страничке jquery-1.9.1.js, jQuery-ui.js а также стили в jquery-ui.css. Скрипты скачаны в папку проекта, подключаются на страничке и отлично работают. Проблема в стилях.
Если я подключаю стили прямой ссылкой на CSS с сайта jQuery, то всё работает отлично:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
```

[image]

Если же скачаю этот CSS-файл и подключу его из папки проекта, то он отображается несовсем корректно (т.е. он работает, но не отображаются кнопк переключения месяцев, хотя физически они работают).

```
<link href="/Content/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

[image]

Если бы CSS вообще не работал (без CSS), то календарик выглядел бы совсем иначе (без фона, без кнопок и т.д.), однако он работает, но без верхних кнопочек.

В чём может быть проблема? Хочу подключить CSS именно из локального хранилища сайта, а не из интернета по ссылке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[@Jembo_by](/users/5398/jembo_by)](/users/5398/jembo_by), В самом css-файле измените пути к изображениям. По умолчанию, вся графика находиться в папке **images**, а сама папка в том же каталоге, что и файл css.

Comment: Благодарю!